# Why am I getting 'cuMemAlloc failed: not initialized' even though I am initializing correctly?

Tags: python, django, cuda, celery, pycuda

I am having some trouble with my Django/Celery/PyCuda setup. 
I am using PyCuda for some image processing on a Amazon EC2 G2 instance. 
Here is the info on my Cuda-capable GRID K520 card:
Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

```
Device 0: "GRID K520"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.0 / 6.0
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294770688 bytes)
( 8) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     1536 CUDA Cores
GPU Clock rate:                                797 MHz (0.80 GHz)
Memory Clock rate:                             2500 Mhz
Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
Total number of registers available per block: 65536
Warp size:                                     32
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
Run time limit on kernels:                     No
Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           0 / 3
Compute Mode:
 < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 6.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 6.0,   NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GRID K520
Result = PASS
```

I am using a pretty out-of-the-box celery config.
I have a set of tasks defined in utils/tasks.py, which are tested and work before attempting to use PyCuda. I installed PyCuda via pip.

At the top of the file that I am having trouble with, I do my standard imports:

```
from celery import task
# other imports
import os
try:
    import Image
except Exception:
    from PIL import Image
import time

#Cuda imports
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
```

A remote server initiates a task, which follows this basic workflow:

```
 @task()
 def photo_function(photo_id,...):
     print 'Got photo...'
     ... Do some stuff ...
     result = do_photo_manipulation(photo_id)
     return result

def do_photo_manipulation(photo_id):
    im = Image.open(inPath)
    px = numpy.array(im)
    px = px.astype(numpy.float32)
    d_px = cuda.mem_alloc(px.nbytes)
    ... (Do stuff with the pixel array) ...
    return new_image
```

This works if I run it in shell plus (ie, ./manage.py shell_plus) and if I run it as a standalone, outside-of-django-and-celery process. It's only in this context it fails, with the error:
    cuMemAlloc failed: not initialized

I have looked at other solutions for a while, and tried putting the import statement to do the initialization in the function itself. I have also plugged in a wait() statement, to ensure it's not a problem of the gpu being ready to do work.

Here is an answer that suggests the error comes from not importing pycuda.autoinit, which I have done: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cuda/1975

Any help here would be appreciated!

If I need to provide any more information, just let me know!

EDIT:
Here is the test code:
    def CudaImageShift(imageIn, mode = "luminosity" , log = 0):

```
    if log == 1 :
        print ("----------> CUDA CONVERSION")

#    print "ENVIRON: "
#    import os
#    print os.environ

    print 'AUTOINIT'
    print pycuda.autoinit

    print 'Making context...'
    context = make_default_context()
    print 'Context created.'
    totalT0 = time.time()

    print 'Doing test run...'
    a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
    a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
    print 'Test mem alloc'
    a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
    print 'MemAlloc complete, test mem copy'
    cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)
    print 'memcopy complete'


[2014-07-15 14:52:20,469: WARNING/Worker-1] cuDeviceGetCount failed: not initialized
```

Comment: Could it be a user permissions issue? Try switching to whoever this runs as inside django, etc and run plainly? Or perhaps your includes are not being processed.

Comment: Why would the includes not be processed?
I don't think it is a permsission error, but I'm not entirely sure how to check.

Comment: It sounds like you are executing your script through some other path, and not directly from the python interpreter. So if includes are spread across multiple files the may not get executed. Also they may change paths.

Comment: The thing is, even if I place the includes inside the function that is doing the CUDA work, no error is thrown and everything gets included. I can use Image (which comes from the included PIL package). pycuda.autoinit doesn't throw an import error when it is included. It just doesn't seem to acutally do it's initialization process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you experience is related to CUDA contexts. As of CUDA 4.0 a CUDA context is required per *process* and *per device*.

Behind the scenes celery will spawn processes for the task workers. When a process/task starts it will not have a context available. In pyCUDA the context creation happens in the autoinit module. That's why your code will work if you run it as a standalone (no extra process is created and the context is valid) or if you put the `import autoinit` inside the CUDA task (Now the process/task will have a context, I believe you tried that already).

If you want to avoid the import you may be able to use the `make_default_context` from `pycuda.tools` although I'm not very familiar with pyCUDA and how it handles context management.

```
from pycuda.tools import make_default_context

@task()
def photo_function(photo_id,...):
  ctx = make_default_context()
  print 'Got photo...'
  ... Do some stuff ...
  result = do_photo_manipulation(photo_id)
  return result
```

Beware that context creation is an expensive process. CUDA deliberately front loads a lot of work in the context in order to avoid non expected delays later on. That's why you have a stack of contexts that you can push/pop between host threads (but not between processes). If your kernel code is very fast you may experience delays because of the context create/destroy procedure.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I really appreciate the help!
I'm still hitting the same error trying to initialize manually. I actually tried this yesterday-- I went into the autoinit function and copied the lines out and straight into my code, to manually initialize PyCuda. No luck. See my edit for code run and error.

Comment: Did you remove the `import autoinit` from the start of your code completely? the cuInit(0) call needs to be done before any call to the API. You get the error when trying to query the number of devices which happens at the beginning of the `make_default_context` function. This gives a hint that the driver is not initialized at all at that point.Also from your code example, is this code inside the function decorated with the celery `@task`?

Comment: I have tried it with _import autoinit_ both removed and not removed. Also, I have tried it with _@task_ decorated and not decorated on the function. All produce the same error.